# mysql: how to obtain current user for last_updated_by column?

Tags: mysql

Most schemas' tables have last_updated_date and last_updated_by columns.  I knew how to populate this in Oracle, but I am now using MySQL.  Could someone please share how to get the mysql system variable that represents the currently logged in database user who is initiating an insert/update on a table?

I have googled and trolled the MySQL docs without much success...

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT USER();
```

so for example...

```
update mytable set last_updated=USER() where id=1024;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Do this to get current user

```
select user()
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
select current_user ()

or

select user()
```

The [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I did scour the mysql docs, but I just couldn't find the right thing.